# C++, different function output when called multiple times

Tags: c++, function

I have the following code:

```
int countLatticePoints(const double radius, const int dimension) {
static std::vector<int> point {};
static int R = static_cast<int>(std::floor(radius));
static int latticePointCount = 0;

for(int i = -R; i <= R; i++) {

    point.push_back(i);

    if(point.size() == dimension) {
        if(PointIsWithinSphere(point,R)) latticePointCount++;
    } else {
        countLatticePoints(R, dimension);
    }

    point.pop_back();
}

return latticePointCount;
}
```

When I make the call countLatticePoints(2.05, 3) I get the result 13 which is correct. Now I change the parameters and then call countLatticePoints(25.5, 1) I get 51 which is also correct.

Now when I call countLatticePoints(2.05, 3) and countLatticePoints(25.5, 1) right after each other in the main program I get 13 and then 18 (instead of 51), I really don't understand what i'm doing wrong ? When I call each one individually without the other I get the correct result but when I call the functions together one after the other my results change.

Comment: My bet would be on those static variables.

Comment: there are some static variables in the function. For each call you add stuff to the `point` vector and this will lead to different results. Maybe you misunderstand `static` in this context. Why do you made this variables static?

Comment: @owacoder that would be just a work around solution. The easiest would be to remove the `static`

Comment: @owacvoder - That's a terrible idea. Worse yet, it won't work because you haven't reset either `R` or `latticePointCount`.

Comment: Your static variable R is changed at each call. The method is called recursively. This means that the variable R changes during the execution of the method. You might have a look at that.

Comment: @RobertKock, actually, part of the problem is that `R` doesn't change. It's initialized once, the first time `countLatticePoints` is called. Any susbsequence call can never change it.

Answer (score 4):

You're misusing `static`.

The second time you call the function, you push additional  values into `point`.

Edit: I hadn't spotted the recursion. that makes things more complex, but `static` is still the wrong answer.

I'd create a 'state' object, and split the function into two. One that recurses, and takes a reference to the 'state' object, and a second one which initialises the state object and calls the first.

```
struct RecurState 
{
  std::vector<int> point;
  int latticePointCount

  RecurState() : latticePointCount(0)
  {
  }
}
```

Outer function:

```
int countLatticePoints(const double radius, const int dimension) 
{
  RecurState state;
  return countLatticeRecurse(radius, dimension, state)
}
```

Recursive function

```
int countLatticeRecurse(const double radius, const int dimension, RecurseState &state)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Local, static variables only get initialized once, on the first function call.